# C# PictureBox DrawLine ploblem

Tags: c#, picturebox

I have a picture box with size 432x322. I would like to draw a line from (50, 50) to (382, 272), but the end point turns out outside the picture box. The part of code is:

```
e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black, 2), new Point(50, 50), new Point(382, 272));
```

How to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you show the line you wanted inside your picturebox. Vertical,Horizontal? or any

Comment: I want to get something like this: [https://i.imgur.com/MIbYkZV.png]

Comment: I actually got this: https://i.imgur.com/AxXL4Wc.png

Comment: Size mode of my PictureBox is normal.